# Isometric topological sort issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, isometric

I've just implemented a **topological sort algorithm** on my isometric game using this guide: https://mazebert.com/2013/04/18/isometric-depth-sorting/

### The issue

Here's a little example (this is just a **drawing** to illustrate my problem because as we say, *a picture is worth a thousand words*), what I'm **expecting is in left** and the **result of the topological sorting algorithm is in right**

[image: example]

So in the **right image**, the problem is that the box is drawn **BEFORE** the character and I'm expecting it to be drawn **AFTER** like in the **left image**.

### Code of the topological sorting algorithm (Typescript)

```
private TopologicalSort2() {
    // https://mazebert.com/2013/04/18/isometric-depth-sorting/

    for(var i = 0; i < this.Stage.children.length; i++) {
        var a = this.Stage.children[i];
        var behindIndex = 0;

        for(var j = 0; j < this.Stage.children.length; j++) {
            if(i == j) {
                continue;
            }

            var b = this.Stage.children[j];

            if(!a.isoSpritesBehind) {
                a.isoSpritesBehind = [];
            }

            if(!b.isoSpritesBehind) {
                b.isoSpritesBehind = [];
            }

            if(b.posX < a.posX + a.sizeX && b.posY < a.posY + a.sizeY && b.posZ < a.posZ + a.sizeZ) {
                a.isoSpritesBehind[behindIndex++] = b;
            }
        }

        a.isoVisitedFlag = 0;
    }

    var _sortDepth = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < this.Stage.children.length; ++i) {
        visitNode(this.Stage.children[i]);
    }

    function visitNode(n: PIXI.DisplayObject) {
        if(n.isoVisitedFlag == 0) {
            n.isoVisitedFlag = 1;

            if(!n.isoSpritesBehind) {
                return;
            }

            for(var i = 0; i < n.isoSpritesBehind.length; i++) {
                if(n.isoSpritesBehind[i] == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    visitNode(n.isoSpritesBehind[i]);
                    n.isoSpritesBehind[i] = null;
                }
            }

            n.isoDepth = _sortDepth++;
        }
    }

    this.Stage.children.sort((a, b) => {
        if(a.isoDepth - b.isoDepth != 0) {
            return a.isoDepth - b.isoDepth;
        }

        return 0;
    });
}
```

### Informations

**Player:**

```
posX: [the x coordinate of the player]
posY: [the y coordinate of the player]
posZ: 0

sizeX: 1
sizeY: 1
sizeZ: 1
```

**Box:**

```
posX: [the x coordinate of the box]
posY: [the y coordinate of the box]
posZ: 0

sizeX: 3
sizeY: 1
sizeZ: 1
```

### X and Y axis

[image: img]

Do you have any idea of the source of this problem? and maybe how to solve it?

Comment: Could you provide the actual x and y coordinates of the two objects, or else define in which direction the Y is directed? Is the Y axis increasing from top-left to bottom-right, or vice versa?

Comment: @trincot question updated. Does it fits your needs?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. It is something I never looked into, but it is an interesting problem. I will have to let it sink in a bit, ... If no-one else does, I will probably answer in a few hours from now ;-)

Comment: A quicker depth transform and sort can be found at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696002/3877726

Comment: @Blindman67, your answer at that other question cannot be used here, since there the depth you give to an object is independent of the position of other, surrounding objects. But imagine two objects at about the same distance from the viewer, but not overlapping, and put a third bar in between them such that the order of drawing becomes important. If you turn that bar 90° on the X-Y plane, the order might also have to change for a correct rendering. So an order an object gets during the drawing *must* take the position of surrounding objects into account, it cannot only depend on its own props

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to determine whether one object is before the other requires a bit more linear algebra.

First of all, I would suggest to translate the coordinates from the "world" coordinates to the "view" 2D coordinates, i.e. to the rows and columns of the display.

Note also that the original Z coordinate does not influence the sort order (imagine that an object would be lifted up along the Z axis: we can find a sort order where this move would not have any impact). So the above-mentioned translation could assume all points are at Z=0.

Let's take this set-up, but depicted from "above", so when looking along the Z axis down to the game floor:

[image]

In the picture there are 7 objects, numbered from 0 to 6. The line of view in the game would be from the bottom-left of this picture. The coordinate system in which I would suggest to translate some points is depicted with the red row/col axis.

The white diagonals in each object link the two points that would be translated and used in the algorithm. The assumption is that when one object is in front of another, their diagonal lines will not intersect. If they would, it would mean that objects are overlapping each other in the game world, which would mean they are like gasses, not solids :) I will assume this is not the case.

One object A could be in front of another object B when in the new coordinate system, the left-most column coordinate of B falls between the two column coordinates of A (or vice versa). There *might* not really be such an overlap when their Z coordinates differ enough, but we can ignore that, because when there is no overlap we can do no harm in specifying a certain order anyway.

Now, when the coordinates indicate an overlap, the coordinates of diagonals (of A and B) must be compared with some linear algebra formula, which will determine which one is in front of the other.

Here is your adapted function that does that:

```
topologicalSort() {
    // Exit if sorting is a non-operation
    if (this.Stage.children.length < 2) return; 
    // Add two translated coordinates, where each of the resulting 
    //   coordinates has a row (top to bottom) and column 
    //   (left to right) part. They represent a position in the final 
    //   rendered view (the screen).  
    // The two pairs of coordinates are translations of the 
    //   points (posX + sizeX, Y, 0) and (posX, posY + sizeY, 0).
    // Z is ignored (0), since it does not influence the order.
    for (let obj of this.Stage.children) {
        obj.leftCol  = obj.posY - obj.posX - obj.sizeX; 
        obj.rightCol = obj.posY - obj.posX + obj.sizeY;
        obj.leftRow  = obj.posY + obj.posX + obj.sizeX;
        obj.rightRow = obj.posY + obj.posX + obj.sizeY;
        obj.isoSpritesBehind = [];
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < this.Stage.children.length; i++) {
        let a = this.Stage.children[i];
        // Only loop over the next objects
        for(let j = i + 1; j < this.Stage.children.length; j++) {
            let b = this.Stage.children[j];
            // Get the two objects in order of left column:
            let c = b.leftCol < a.leftCol ? b : a;
            let d = b.leftCol < a.leftCol ? a : b;
            // See if they overlap in the view (ignoring Z):
            if (d.leftCol < c.rightCol) {
                // Determine which is behind: some linear algebra
                if (d.leftRow < 
                        (d.leftCol - c.leftCol)/(c.rightCol - c.leftCol) 
                        * (c.rightRow - c.leftRow)  + c.leftRow) {
                    // c is in front of d
                    c.isoSpritesBehind.push(d);
                } else { // d is in front of c
                    d.isoSpritesBehind.push(c);
                }
            } // in the else-case it does not matter which one comes first
        }
    }

    // This replaces your visitNode function and call:
    this.Stage.children.forEach(function getDepth(obj) {
        // If depth was already assigned, this node was already visited
        if (!obj.isoDepth) {
            // Get depths recursively, and retain the maximum of those.
            // Add one more to get the depth for the current object
            obj.isoDepth = obj.isoSpritesBehind.length
                ? 1+Math.max(...obj.isoSpritesBehind.map(getDepth))
                : 1; // Depth when there is nothing behind it
        }
        return obj.isoDepth; // Return it for easier recursion
    });

    // Sort like you did, but in shorter syntax
    this.Stage.children.sort((a, b) => a.isoDepth - b.isoDepth);
}
```

I add a snippet where I completed the class with a minimum of code, enough to make it run and output the final order in terms of object index numbers (as they were originally inserted):

```js
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.Stage = { children: [] };
    }
    addObject(posX, posY, posZ, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ) {
        this.Stage.children.push({posX, posY, posZ, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, 
                id: this.Stage.children.length}); // add a unique id
    }
    topologicalSort() {
        // Exit if sorting is a non-operation
        if (this.Stage.children.length < 2) return; 
        // Add two translated coordinates, where each of the resulting 
        //   coordinates has a row (top to bottom) and column 
        //   (left to right) part. They represent a position in the final 
        //   rendered view (the screen).  
        // The two pairs of coordinates are translations of the 
        //   points (posX + sizeX, Y, 0) and (posX, posY + sizeY, 0).
        // Z is ignored (0), since it does not influence the order.
        for (let obj of this.Stage.children) {
            obj.leftCol  = obj.posY - obj.posX - obj.sizeX; 
            obj.rightCol = obj.posY - obj.posX + obj.sizeY;
            obj.leftRow  = obj.posY + obj.posX + obj.sizeX;
            obj.rightRow = obj.posY + obj.posX + obj.sizeY;
            obj.isoSpritesBehind = [];
        }
        
        for(let i = 0; i < this.Stage.children.length; i++) {
            let a = this.Stage.children[i];
            // Only loop over the next objects
            for(let j = i + 1; j < this.Stage.children.length; j++) {
                let b = this.Stage.children[j];
                // Get the two objects in order of left column:
                let c = b.leftCol < a.leftCol ? b : a;
                let d = b.leftCol < a.leftCol ? a : b;
                // See if they overlap in the view (ignoring Z):
                if (d.leftCol < c.rightCol) {
                    // Determine which is behind: some linear algebra
                    if (d.leftRow < 
                            (d.leftCol - c.leftCol)/(c.rightCol - c.leftCol) 
                            * (c.rightRow - c.leftRow)  + c.leftRow) {
                        // c is in front of d
                        c.isoSpritesBehind.push(d);
                    } else { // d is in front of c
                        d.isoSpritesBehind.push(c);
                    }
                } // in the else-case it does not matter which one comes first
            }
        }
        
        // This replaces your visitNode function and call:
        this.Stage.children.forEach(function getDepth(obj) {
            // If depth was already assigned, this node was already visited
            if (!obj.isoDepth) {
                // Get depths recursively, and retain the maximum of those.
                // Add one more to get the depth for the current object
                obj.isoDepth = obj.isoSpritesBehind.length
                    ? 1+Math.max(...obj.isoSpritesBehind.map(getDepth))
                    : 1; // Depth when there is nothing behind it
            }
            return obj.isoDepth; // Return it for easier recursion
        });

        // Sort like you did, but in shorter syntax
        this.Stage.children.sort((a, b) => a.isoDepth - b.isoDepth);
    }
    toString() { // Just print the ids of the children
        return JSON.stringify(this.Stage.children.map( x => x.id ));
    }
}

const game = new Game();
game.addObject( 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
game.addObject( 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1 );
game.addObject( 6, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1 );
game.addObject( 9, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
game.addObject( 5, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1 );
game.addObject( 7, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1 );
game.addObject( 8, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1 );
game.topologicalSort();
console.log(game + '');
```

The objects in the snippet are the same as in the picture with the same numbers. The output order is `[0,1,4,2,5,6,3]` which is the valid sequence for drawing the objects.